# Proving joint cdf equality?

Tags: probability-theory

Show that for any $x_1 < x_2$ and $y_1 < y_2$ one has
$P(x_1 < X ≤ x_2, y_1 < Y ≤ y_2) = F(x_2, y_2) + F(x_1, y_1) − F(x_1, y_2) − F(x_2, y_1)$.

Would I just need to split the LHS to something that gives me the right?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\begin{aligned}\mathsf{P}\left(x_{1}<X\leq x_{2},y_{1}<Y\leq y_{2}\right) & =\mathsf{E}1_{\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right]}\left(X\right)1_{\left(y_{1},y_{2}\right]}\left(Y\right)\\
 & =\mathsf{E}\left[1_{\left(\infty,x_{2}\right]}\left(X\right)-1_{\left(\infty,x_{1}\right]}\left(X\right)\right]\left[1_{\left(\infty,y_{2}\right]}\left(Y\right)-1_{\left(\infty,y_{1}\right]}\left(Y\right)\right]\\
 & =\cdots
\end{aligned}
$

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to the identity $\Bbb P(a< X\leq b) = F_X(b) - F_X(a)$ in the scalar case, where $F_X$ is the c.d.f. of $X$. Here,
\begin{aligned}
&\Bbb P(x_1 < X \leq x_2, y_1 < Y \leq y_2)\\ =\; &\Bbb P(x_1 < X \leq x_2, Y \leq y_2) - \Bbb P(x_1 < X \leq x_2, Y \leq y_1) \\=\; &\Bbb P(X \leq x_2, Y \leq y_2) - \Bbb P(X \leq x_1, Y \leq y_2) \\ &\quad - \Bbb P(X \leq x_2, Y \leq y_1) + \Bbb P(X \leq x_1, Y \leq y_1)
\end{aligned}